# How to list the values of a json object that are equal to key in an array?

Tags: javascript, json

```js
const columns = ['dataA', 'dataD', 'dataB', 'dataE'];

const data = [{
    dataA: '001a',
    dataB: '123456',
    dataC: 'true',
    dataD: 'normal',
    dataE: 'ON'
  },
  {
    dataA: '002a',
    dataB: '123456',
    dataC: 'true',
    dataD: 'exception',
    dataE: 'ON'
  },
  {
    dataA: '003a',
    dataB: '098767',
    dataC: 'true',
    dataD: 'normal',
    dataE: 'OFF'
  },
  {
    dataA: '001a',
    dataB: '567890',
    dataC: 'false',
    dataD: 'normal',
    dataE: 'ON'
  }
];

const result = data.map(a => columns.map(k => {
  return {
    [k]: a[k]
  };
}));

console.log(result);
```

I managed to filter the values but, now each key and value is an object. How can i modify the code so that i get the result with the same structure as data?

i need the result to be in this format:

```
[
  { dataA: "001a", dataD: "normal", dataB: "123456", dataE: "ON" }
  { dataA: "002a", dataD: "exception", dataB: "123456", dataE: "ON" }
  { dataA: "003a", dataD: "normal", dataB: "098767", dataE: "OFF" }
  { dataA: "001a", dataD: "normal", dataB: "567890", dataE: "ON" }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spread the results of the inner map into Object#assign combine them to a single object:

```js
const columns = ['dataA', 'dataD', 'dataB', 'dataE'];

const data = [{"dataA":"001a","dataB":"123456","dataC":"true","dataD":"normal","dataE":"ON"},{"dataA":"002a","dataB":"123456","dataC":"true","dataD":"exception","dataE":"ON"},{"dataA":"003a","dataB":"098767","dataC":"true","dataD":"normal","dataE":"OFF"},{"dataA":"001a","dataB":"567890","dataC":"false","dataD":"normal","dataE":"ON"}];

const result = data.map(a => Object.assign(...columns.map(k => ({
  [k]: a[k]
}))));

console.log(result);
```

Or create the object using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of map:

```js
const columns = ['dataA', 'dataD', 'dataB', 'dataE'];

const data = [{"dataA":"001a","dataB":"123456","dataC":"true","dataD":"normal","dataE":"ON"},{"dataA":"002a","dataB":"123456","dataC":"true","dataD":"exception","dataE":"ON"},{"dataA":"003a","dataB":"098767","dataC":"true","dataD":"normal","dataE":"OFF"},{"dataA":"001a","dataB":"567890","dataC":"false","dataD":"normal","dataE":"ON"}];

const result = data.map(a => columns.reduce((r, k) => (r[k] = a[k], r), {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Awesome, used the reduce instead of map. When i used the map with Object#assign i got a TSLint error: Expected at least 1 arguments, but got a minimum of 0.

Comment: @Takebo - shame on TSLint :) However, I prefer the reduce method since it doesn't create temporary objects.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right path. Note that **object properties are inherently unordered**, don't rely on them being in a particular order.

```js
const columns = ['dataA', 'dataD', 'dataB', 'dataE'];

const data = [{ dataA: '001a', dataB: '123456', dataC: 'true', dataD: 'normal', dataE: 'ON' }, { dataA: '002a', dataB: '123456', dataC: 'true', dataD: 'exception', dataE: 'ON' }, { dataA: '003a', dataB: '098767', dataC: 'true', dataD: 'normal', dataE: 'OFF' }, { dataA: '001a', dataB: '567890', dataC: 'false', dataD: 'normal', dataE: 'ON' }];

const result = data.map(a => columns.reduce((acc, curr) => ({
  ...acc, [curr]: a[curr]
}), {}))

console.log(result);

/*
[
  {
    "dataA": "001a",
    "dataD": "normal",
    "dataB": "123456",
    "dataE": "ON"
  },
  {
    "dataA": "002a",
    "dataD": "exception",
    "dataB": "123456",
    "dataE": "ON"
  },
  {
    "dataA": "003a",
    "dataD": "normal",
    "dataB": "098767",
    "dataE": "OFF"
  },
  {
    "dataA": "001a",
    "dataD": "normal",
    "dataB": "567890",
    "dataE": "ON"
  }
]
*/
```

Comment: "**object properties are inherently unordered**" Thank you, didn't know about that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the inner `map` you need a `reduce` onto an object:

```
const result = data.map(a => columns.reduce((obj, k) => {
  obj[k] = a[k];
  return obj;
}, {}));
```

Note that object properties don’t have an inherent order.